# How to add two projects from one workspace to git in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have two projects in Intellij Idea conjoined together in "Maven Projects" tool window...:
- autotests
- testframework

Question: **How can I add both projects to the git version control?**

I did: "*VCS | Enable Version Control Integration*"

But this added only one project to the git: autotests

**How can I add "testframework" project also?**

Whene I went this way: "*Associating a Directory with a Specific Version Control System*" and associated testframework directory to the git, it shows me:

> Invalid Git root mapping The directory
>   /Users/user/Projects/testframework is registered as a Git root, but no
>   Git repositories were found there.

And anyway all git commands from VCS menu seemed to be correspondent only to "autotests" project....

Comment: In `Settings` | `Version Control` set both roots to Git.

Comment: You mean to the root folder of the autotests and testframework?

Comment: Yes, one mapping per git root.

Comment: This error only occur if your project not configure proper or invalid source directory